# Can we create class with name "class"?

Tags: c#

Lets forgot about why I need this.

Can we create a class with name "class".

Below code resulted in compilation error as class is a reserve keyword.

```
public class class
{

}
```

so is there any hack or a way to fool C# compiler? :)

This Question was asked by interviewer in my last interview and he told me it is possible.

Comment: You classes should have UpperCase Names `Class` anyway.

Comment: Adding to Alex's fine comment - _[DO name **classes** and structs with nouns or noun phrases, using **PascalCasing**.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)_

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use:

```
public class @class
{ 

}
```

But why do you want that?

[C# Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special
>   meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your
>   program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a valid
>   identifier but if is not because if is a keyword.

---

What i've learned from this answer was that new key-words won't be added globally but only as contextual key-words  to avoid breaking programs written in earlier versions. You find a list in the link above.

So interestingly enough this is valid(better: compiling) code:

```
public class var
{
    public void foo()
    {
        var var = new var();
    }
}
```

Here's another one:

```
public class dynamic
{
    public void foo()
    {
        dynamic dynamic = new dynamic(); 
    }
}
```

But never do this. It will break  your other code where you've used `var` or `dynamic` before.

Comment: This is not a thing you'd want in handwritten code, but it can happen in generated code quite often, i.e. if you have a table called *Classes*, *Groups*, etc  and let a ORM generate code for it

Comment: As I mentioned above that question was asked in one of my interview so I was looking for solution. Thanks It works. just waiting for 15 min to accept answer.

Comment: @JineshJain It's important to note that the `@` is "interpreted" at the C# compiler level. When it is compiled, the function will be `class`, not `@class` (you can see it if you disassemble the code) see for example http://goo.gl/mmyLQU

Answer (score 8):

Yet another alternative is through Unicode

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        cl\u0061ss a = new cl\u0061ss();
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().Name);
    }
}

public class cl\u0061ss
{


}
```

**Note**: `Console.WriteLine()` will print **class**

DotNetFiddle link is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OZdkGp).

Comment: Should go to the obfuscated C# contest

Comment: @DrKoch ha ha... I just got that Idea from msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @DrKoch Yes I strongly agree with you They just for the fun :). It is against the clean code and this kind of code is not even human redable.

Comment: @jenish - thanks for providing some other way. as we are not going to use this approaches in our practical scenarios and my question is all about knows the ways we can achieve this.

Answer (score -3):

Most programmers use underscore '_' at the beginning of the name of a variable or whatsoever if it is a reserved word e.g.

```
public class _class
{

}
```

variable declarations example

```
int _int;
```

Comment: But then the classname is "_class" and not "class" as requested by (the interviewer of) the OP.